# Does the equation $x^n\equiv 1\pmod p$ has at most $n$ solutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Does the equation $x^n\equiv 1\pmod p$, $p$ being a prime has at most $n$ solutions? If it does, how to show it? (I don't know a thing about fields.)

Comment: Have you covered basic ring theory? Such as integral domains and polynomial rings over such? The answer comes quickly from there, but is trickier otherwise.

Comment: Is the operation addition or multiplication?  I.e. are we working in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, but No

Comment: @KajHansen multi

Comment: I'm confused because I can choose $p = 2$ and $n = 1$ and then choose $x = 1, 3, 5, 7, ...$ such that $x^1 = 1 \mod 2$

Comment: @Jared Yes, but they are equivalent to each other:$1\equiv 3\mod2$,$3\equiv 5\mod2$

Comment: @pxc3110 I don't understand what is meant by $x = 2\lambda + 1$ being equivalent to each other (admittedly I may not understand the terminology), but if you are saying that they are _all_ equal mod 2, then I agree...but then this is a property of the modulus.  Any number mod $p$ will have _at most_ $p$ different values (this is simply the definition of the modulus).

Comment: And it seems to me that any number, prime or not can have an infinite number of solutions to $x^n = 1\mod p$, since you can construct $x = \lambda p+ 1$ such that $\left(\lambda p + 1\right)^n = 1 + \sum_1^n \binom{n}{i}\lambda^ip^i = 1 + p\sum_0^{n - 1} \binom{n}{i + 1}\lambda^{i + 1}p^i$.

Comment: BTW this is called Lagrange's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28number_theory%29

Comment: @Jared Let me clarify: We're finding equivalent classes(sets) where every elements in it is a solution. Such class of x is a set of all elements equivalent to x. And a is equivalent to b iff $a\equiv b\mod p$

Comment: @Jared "this is a property of the modulus" No.  It isn't $x^p \equiv 1$, it's $x^n \equiv 1$.  So there are at most $p$ different solutions, yes, but it's nontrivial to show that there are also at most $n$ different solutions.

Comment: @Goos Ahh, I actually misread the question when I made that statement (my statement was correct, it's just I said $p$ when the question specified $n$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Theorem (Lagrange).** If $\newcommand{\polynn}[3]{{#1_{#3}#2^{#3}+#1_{#3-1}#2^{#3-1}+\ldots+#1_0}}f(x)=\polynn axn$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, $p$ is a prime and $p\nmid a_n$, then the congruence $\newcommand{\kong}[3]{{#1\equiv #2\pmod{#3}}}\kong{f(x)}0p$ has at most $n$ solutions (modulo $p$).
>
> Equivalently, if this congruence has more than $n$ (non-congruent) solutions, then $p$ divides all coefficients of the polynomial $f(x)$.

*Proof.* By induction on $n$.

For $n=1$ this follows from the well-known result about solutions of linear congruences $\kong{ax+b}0p$. (We know that the number of solutions is $\gcd(a,p)=1$.

Suppose the claim is true for $n-1$. Suppose $x_0,\dots,x_n$ would be $n+1$ diferent solutions of $\kong{f(x)}0p$. Then we have
$$f(x)-f(x_0)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(x^k-x_0^k)=  (x-x_0)\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}x_0+x^{k-3}x_0^2+\ldots +x_0^{k-1})=(x-x_0)g(x),$$
where $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ with the leading coefficient $a_n$.

So we get $\kong{(x_i-x_0)g(x_i)}0p$ and $\kong{g(x_i)}0p$ for each $i=1,\ldots,n$. Thus $\kong{g(x)}0p$ has $n$ solutions. None of these solutions are congruent modulo $p$. This contradicts the inductive hypothesis. $\hspace{3cm}\square$

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: The OP wants an elementary proof, which this is not.**

Yes.  We can show by induction that for any monic polynomial $P$ of degree $n$, $P(x) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has at most $n$ solutions.
In particular, take $P(x) = x^n - 1$.

- **Base case** $x + c \equiv 0$ has exactly one solution.
- **Inductive step** Consider the equation $P(x) \equiv 0 \pmod p$, where $P(x)$ is monic of degree $n+1$.
  If it has no solutions, we are done.  Otherwise, it has some solution $a$.
  Then, because the ring of polynomials over a base field [forms a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain#Examples) (hence a UFD), we can factor
  $P(x) = (x - a)Q(x)$ for some monic $Q$ of degree $n$.  By inductive hypothesis, $Q$ has at most $n$ solutions, so $P$ has at most $n+1$.

Comment: You are missing the point of $p$ being a prime, as the case of the polynomial $x^{2} - 1$ modulo $8$ shows. It factors as $(x-1)(x+1)$ alright, but then $\pm 3$ are also solutions.

Comment: I agree, your proof doesn't even mention that p is a prime. I think something must be wrong

Comment: @AndreasCaranti That is a good point.  I think the fact that $p$ is prime is probably hidden in the step where I factored $P(x) = (x-a)Q(x)$.  This isn't really a good proof.

Comment: That, and the fact that if $\alpha$ is a root of $P(x) = (x - a) Q(x)$, then $(\alpha - a) Q(\alpha) = 0$. Now the integers modulo a prime form a field, so one of the two factors must be zero.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you, but I don't know a thing about"fields"

Comment: My comment was meant for @Goos. In elementary terms, if a *prime* divides the product $(\alpha - a) Q(\alpha)$, then it must divide one of the factors.

Comment: The assumption that $p$ is prime happens when you say "the ring of polynomials over a base field...", since the "base field" you're referring to is only a field if $p$ is prime.

Comment: @pxc3110, the answer uses (implicitly) that $\mathbb{Z}/ p \mathbb{Z}$ is a field, thus $p$ is prime.

Comment: @vonbrand Yep, the field thing was added up after I said that. In the first version, it was more implicit, so I was a little bit doubtful.

Comment: This answer is more advanced, yet shorter. It's not a bad one.thanks